# Help understanding LP transformation to standard form

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am facing some difficulty understanding a LP problem. The objective function and the constraints:
$$
\begin{split}
max. & \sum{A_{t}} \times p_{t}\\st.
L_{0} & =0\\
L_{t} & =L_{t-1}+A_{t-1}; t > 0\\
-1 & \leq A_{t} \leq 1\\
0 & \leq L_{t} \leq 3 \\
where:
\\ t & = 1,...,120 
\end{split}
$$

The problem is to maximize the profit of a battery. The current level of the battery is $L_t$ and the action in each time period is $A_t$. The initial level of the battery is $L_t$. So, the battery can be charged $A_t=-1$ three periods in a row until $L_t$ = 3, then the only option is to discharge $A_t=1$.

$p_t$ is a time series of forecasted value so if we discharge the battery at time $t$, we earn $p_t \times A_t$, if we charge at $t$ we spend $p_t \times -A_t$
$A_t$ is a action taken at each time period $t$, $L_t$ is the maximum level

I want to formulate this as the standard problem, to be able to implement it into Python. Based on this I guess that the last two constraint would have to be transformed into the following four constraints.

```
  A_t + s_1 = 1
- A_t + s_2 = 1
  L_t + s_3 = 3
- L_t + s_4 = 0
```

But I am not sure of this. Further, I don't know how to tacle the initial constraint `L_0=0` or the second constraint including the `t-1` index. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions posted here should be self-contained.

Comment: Please don't post images. Instead, you can directly use LaTex here, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for more details. In addition, you should explain your notation a bit. Is each $A_t$ and $L_t$ just a scalar variable? For instance, most people (including me) use upper letters only for matrices, not for scalars. Also, what is your objective function and what is $t0$?

Comment: *"I don't know how to tacle the initial constraint L_0=0 or the second constraint including the t-1 index"* I would say that  $t$ is defined for natural numbers, **without 0**.

Comment: @joni Thank you for the tip. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks. I have fixed that now.

Comment: @SimonRydstedt Now it looks fine so far. But you have to add the non-negativity constraint for the $s_i$.

Comment: These days it is not necessary to pack your problem into one or another standard form yourself in order to pass it to a solver. Modelling tools like cvxpy, pyomo, pulp etc. will do it for you and all you need is to write your problem in a high-level formulation that is a direct translation of the equations you wrote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LP in standard form looks like this:

$$
\min c^\top x \quad \text{s.t.} \quad Hx = d, \quad l \leq x \leq u.
$$

You only need to to two things:

1. Pack all your variables into one vector, i.e. you can set $x = (L_0, A_0, L_1, A_1, \ldots, L_{120}, A_{120}) \in \mathbb{R}^{242}$.
2. Set the objective vector $c$. With the choice of $x$ you have

$$
c = (0, p_0, 0, p_1, 0, p_2, 0, p_3, \ldots, 0, p_{120})^\top
$$

3. Write your constraints as matrix-vector product.

This isn't hard, as you have

$$
- L_{t-1} - A_{t-1} + L_t = 0
$$

for $t \geq 1$ and $L_0 = 0$. I think it helps to explicitly write these constraints:

$$
\begin{align*}
- L_0 - A_0 + L_1 &= 0, \\
- L_1 - A_1 + L_2 &= 0, \\
- L_2 - A_2 + L_3 &= 0, \\
 &\vdots \\
- L_{119} - A_{119} + L_{120} &= 0
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore, we have

$$
\underbrace{%
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
& & & \vdots & & & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -1 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
}_{=H}
\cdot
\underbrace{%
\begin{pmatrix}
L_0 \\ A_0 \\ L_1 \\ A_1 \\ \vdots \\ L_{120} \\ A_{120}
\end{pmatrix}
}_{=x}
=
\underbrace{%
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
}_{=d}.
$$

Here, $H \in \mathbb{R}^{120 \times 242}$ is a matrix with 120 rows and 242 columns. Your variable bounds are then given by

$$
\begin{align*}
l &= (0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, \ldots, 0, -1)^\top, \\
u &= (0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1 \ldots, 3, 1)^\top.
\end{align*}
$$

Note that the upper and lower bound for $L_0$ is 0 due to the equation $L_0=0$. Alternatively, you could incorporate this equation into the matrix $H$ instead. It would be just another row with a 1 in the first column and zeros for the other ones.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this. In the vector `x`.  What are the values of $L_0$, $A_0$ etc. supposed to be when I create the vector in Python to later pass it to the solver?

Comment: I suppose that I might not need to do this. But what about the requirement that the `c` vector should have the same size as the number of columns in `H`. Now `c=240` and `H=242`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your first question. You just solve the LP. Then, the solver gives you the solution $x$ and you can split the solution back into $L_0, A_0$ etc using the the above definition afterwards. Regarding your second comment: The vector c already has 242 entries. Otherwise, the scalar product $c^\top x$ wouldn't be defined.

Comment: Hm, okay. When I read it I understand it as the vector $c$ should contain $0, p_0, 0, p_1$ etc. But this only gives 240 values since there are 120 $p_i$s

Comment: Well. I feel a bit stupid. If there are only 120 $p_i$ I guess the list should only go to $p_{119}$ if it starts at $p_0$ and therefore $H$ should have only 240 columns too. I struggle with implementing $H$ though since the `-1, -1, 1` sequence stop at column 121,  while in your example the last three columns are also non-zero.

Comment: Well, you didn't provide any indices for the sum in the objective, so I assumed you have $p_0, \ldots, p_{120}$. If so, you have 121 entries $p_i$. There are 120 entries from $p_1$ to $p_{120}$ and one additional entry $p_0$. Similarly, you have 121 zeros in the $c$ vector, which are just the objective coefficients of the $L_i$'s. Therefore, 2*121=242 entries.

Comment: Yes. I wasn't clear about that. I think I have managed to compile the correct matrices and vectors now, but I get an error when trying to run `scipy.linprog`. First, it wants the number of rows of $H$ to be the same as the size of $d$, so I do $H^T$ and try again. Then it gives me the error that the number of columns in $H$ should be the as the size of $c$. Since both $d$ and $c$ have the size 240, this would require $H$ to be 240*240?

Comment: It's impossible to help properly if you don't provide all information in your initial question. And tbh it's not really motivating to answer additional questions that are due to unclear informations. $H \cdot x = d$ already tells you that $d$ has the same number of entries as $H$ has rows. So, in your case $d$ is just a vector with 120 zeros as $H$ as 120 rows. The number of rows in $H$ is just the number of linear equations while the number of columns of $H$ is the number of variables. I'd recommend to make yourself familiar with the basics of matrices and vectors.

Comment: I understand that. I am doing my best to provide sufficient information, and I am also aware that I lack in basic understanding of these problems. I appreciate your help a lot.